# Getting OpenVR tracking quality without SteamVR

Tags: tracking, virtual-reality, openvr

Is it possible to get real-time data about the HMD tracking quality via OpenVR? In SteamVR you can see a warning when your headset if not being tracked correctly. Is it possible to get that info via OpenVR API only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVR is the public part of SteamVR, you cant have one without the other, especially if you're an application